# uname -p -i are unknown

Tags: utilities, coreutils

Why does this happen? Everything else printable with `uname` is shown.
I am not looking into fixing this. Even the manual page of `uname` says that it's a common output.

I just want to know why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html) doesn't define `-p` or `-i`. In [GNU `coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uname-invocation.html#uname-invocation) they are marked as non-portable, as you indicate. The [default implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/uname.c#n300) relies on two optional operating system features, the three-argument form of [`sysinfo(2)`](http://manpage.me/?query=sysinfo&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS%205.10&arch=default&format=html) (from SunOS) and the six-argument form of [`sysctl(3)`](http://manpage.me/?query=sysctl&sektion=3) (from the BSDs); neither of these are available on Linux.

Thus on Debian and derived distributions (apart from Ubuntu and its derivatives), you simply get `unknown`.

On Fedora and related distributions, `uname` is [patched](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/rpms/coreutils/blob/master/f/coreutils-8.2-uname-processortype.patch) to return the machine type (`-m`) as processor (`-p`) and hardware platform (`-i`), with the latter tweaked to produce `i386` for any value of the form `i?86`.

On Ubuntu and derivatives, a [variant](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/coreutils/vivid/view/head:/debian/patches/80_fedora_sysinfo.dpatch) of the Fedora patch is used, which additionally checks for AMD CPUs on `i686` processors and produces `athlon` instead.

Comment: Thanks! And I guess they didn't remove the options to not build a difference in usage between distros.

Comment: Yes — if you're running GNU `coreutils`' `uname`, the options are always there (well, since they were introduced, I didn't check when that happened), but they might not return anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

Read the `info` page, it is more detailed:

> ‘-i’
>
> ‘--hardware-platform’
>
> ```
>  Print the hardware platform name (sometimes called the hardware
>  implementation).  Print ‘unknown’ if the kernel does not make this
>  information easily available, as is the case with Linux kernels.
> ```
>
> ‘-p’
>
> ‘--processor’
>
> ```
>  Print the processor type (sometimes called the instruction set
>  architecture or ISA). Print ‘unknown’ if the kernel does not make
>  this information easily available, as is the case with Linux
>  kernels.
> ```