# Linux package managers for ARM devices

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, repository, arm

Normally package managers like `apt` work  for X86 and X64 systems.

How does the Linux package manager `apt`running on a Rasberry Pi for example know that the binaries to be fetched and installed must be for the ARM platform?

We simply run `sudo apt-get install` just like on any other device.

Where is this specified on the device about how to locate the correct packages?

Comment: `uname -i` is enough

Comment: @Artem on Debian-based systems (apart from Ubuntu) that’s not going to get you very far, [`uname -i` outputs “unknown”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307960/86440).

Comment: LOL why? Weird, :-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov So the package management system will check for the type of architecture used on the system first, and then get the correct packages from upstream ?

Answer (score 1):

`apt` and `.deb` packages aren’t specific to x86 architectures; Debian in particular supports [many different architectures](https://buildd.debian.org/), including `arm64`, `armel` and `armhf`.

On Debian-based systems, [including Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html), the system architecture is defined as the architecture of the `dpkg` package, and is shown by

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

This is typically set by whatever installation image was used (which has to be appropriate for the system in use), but it can be changed after installation by cross-grading (*e.g.* `i386` to `amd64`).

`apt` installs packages for the `dpkg`-determined architecture by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are dkpg packages also used for an ARM device? This i am not sure about

Comment: `.deb` packages are used on Debian derivatives on any supported architecture; on Debian, that includes [`arm64`, `armel` and `armhf`](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) among many others.

Comment: But the Rasberry Pi doesn't use Debian. So how does this work?

Comment: “Debian-based”. Raspberry Pi OS is Debian-based, *i.e.* it’s a Debian derivative.

Comment: How then would we get a package management system working for Linux which is not a Debian derivative. If we generated the system using Yocto for example.

Comment: That’s a completely different question. You’d use whatever package management system the target system uses, if any; some embedded systems like Yocto don’t use a package management system on the devices themselves, you’re supposed to build an image for the embedded system externally.